# How to display a message if a search in an input box using JS do not return any result?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following code from [this page on W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp). It works very well but I'm having troubles to display a message if no one result is found. I suppose that I have to use something like the lenght of the `filter.indexOf`, but I don't know how.

*P.S.: I've found some answers using jQuery, but I need to use pure JavaScript.*

Does anyone have any idea how can I do this?

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Simply use a flag variable for this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a working snippet. Add an extra list element that says 'No matching result', keep a flag that says matchFound which is set to true as soon as a match is found in the list. At the end if the matchFound flag is still false, set the display property of the 'Not match found' item to block and this will do the trick

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var matchFound = false;
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  if (!filter) {
    var els = document.getElementById('not-found').style.display = 'none';
  }
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      matchFound = true;
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  if (!matchFound) {
    document.getElementById('not-found').style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```css
#not-found {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
  <li id="not-found"><a href="#">No matching results</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Glad could help :)